# Using google maps to tell the robot where to go

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently working on an autonomous boat project, I was wondering if there is way to choose a point on google maps and plug it into ROS terminal to tell the boat to go to that coordinate?

Much Appricated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286317/using-google-maps-to-tell-the-robot-where-to-go/) by [bobl](https://answers.ros.org/users/34282/bobl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're really asking two questions here: 1) How do you convert a geographic coordinate into a coordinate in your boat's map frame, and 2) How do you navigate to a point in your boat's map frame. The details of the answers will depend a lot on your setup, but I'll give some high level ideas for each.

**For 1:**

If you are okay with doing some manual work every time you want to move your boat, you can convert the lat-long coordinates of the point you want to move to into UTM coordinates. Assuming you are localizing your boat with GPS, you should be able to convert the UTM coordinates into coordinates in your boat's map frame.

If you want to be able to click a point on a map and automatically have your boat navigate to that point, a good starting point would be to look at the ROS packages [RVizSatellite](https://github.com/gareth-cross/rviz_satellite) and [mapviz](https://github.com/swri-robotics/mapviz), which can both be used to display maps (maps are generated using [map tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map)). Something to note though is that Google map tiles are only officially available through their [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile), which you'll need a key to use. There are free map tile providers though (like [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/)), which you can use with RVizSatellie & mapviz.

**For 2:**

Once you have the coordinates of your desired position in your boat's map frame, you should be able to use the existing ros navigation stack for sending commands (see tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation#Basic_ROS_Navigation_Tutorials)).

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [Mapviz](https://github.com/swri-robotics/mapviz) with plugin [Point Click Publisher](https://github.com/swri-robotics/mapviz#point-click-publisher).

To set your goal to Navigation Stack you can use [gps_goal](https://github.com/danielsnider/gps_goal). But Point Click Publisher publish point using [geometry_msgs::PointStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PointStamped.html) and gps_goal listen for [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) or [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html). You need modify gps_goal or convert message to required type for your purpose.

To display Google Maps in Mapviz you can use this [solution](https://github.com/danielsnider/MapViz-Tile-Map-Google-Maps-Satellite).

Edit 1: Now gps_goal using NED reference frame, according [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) convention

---

Originally posted by [Stepan Kostusiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/36328/stepan-kostusiev/) with karma: 11 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manuelmelvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30611/manuelmelvin/) on 2019-11-08**:
Hello Stepan,
Do you have any document about the installation steps about Mapviz or Rviz satellite. I tried to install both, but both throwing some errors. I think I need to download some libraries for making it work. But I didnt find any documents for that. Requesting you help

Thanks
Melvin